# What is the difference between matrix.size() and matrix[0].size()?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

In the code below, what exactly is the difference between `matrix.size()` and `matrix[0].size()`?

```
int matrixElementsSum(std::vector<std::vector<int>> m) {
    int s = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < m[0].size(); j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
            if (m[i][j] == 0) {
                break;
            }
            s += m[i][j];
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> m(10, std::vector(20);
```

`m.size()` will be 10, the number of `std::vector<int>`s in `m`.
`m[0].size()` will be 20, the number `int`s in `m[0]`.

Comparing that to a 2D array, if you have:

```
int m[10][20];
```

`sizeof(m)/sizeof(m[0])` will be 10, the number of rows in `m`.
`sizeof(m[0])/sizeof(m[0][0])` will be 20, the number of columns in `m[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

The exact meaning is the following. There are no real 2d vectors in C++ but there are `std::vector<T>` containing `std::vector<T>`.

If you declare a vector `std::vector<int> vec(10)` you have a vector containing 10 elements. So `vec.size()` is 10.

If you declare `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(10, std::vector<int>(10))` you have a vector with 10 elements and each element contains a vector containing 10 elements. Therefore `vec[0]` is of type `std::vector<int>`.

If you want to know how much elements this vector (meaning `vec[0]`) contains, you can easily do `vec[0].size()`.

If you want the total number of elements you have to count how much vectors are contained in `vec` multiplied with the number of elements each of these vectors containe. Therefore `vec.size()*vec[0].size()`.

Lets' conclude:

We have `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(10,std::vector<int>(10))`:

- Number of rows (the number of `std::vector<int>` contained in `vec`): `vec.size()`
- Number of columns (the number of elements contained in each `std::vector<int>`): `vec[0].size()`
- Total number of elements: `vec.size()*vec[0].size()`